# xcode 4 distribution build problem

Tags: macos, xcode4

When trying to test my application created in XCode 4 on another computer (sent from an archive, just like the user guide says to do), I get this error in console. Any ideas?

3/27/11 10:20:16 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[106]  ([0x0-0x27be7bc].xxx.test[86534]) posix_spawn("/Users/Matt/Dropbox/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test", ...): Permission denied

The permissions appear to be fine on everything, I can't figure it out.

Comment: apple is watching you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox does strange things to file permissions in bundles (Mac / iOS apps are bundles). It seems like you changed Xcode's default build folders (now called "derived data", etc.) to point at this DropBox folder. Don't do that.

Make sure the app is built somewhere aside from this folder and I'll bet it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I built the project in the normal location, and only transferred it to the other computer via dropbox though.

Comment: ... which is, as I explained, a problem: DropBox kills app bundles. Zip it up after you build it before using DropBox to transfer it.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your answer. You were right, dropbox was messing with the permissions. Thanks again!

Comment: I had the same problem. I zipped the file as Joshua suggested and I resolved this issue!